# iscsiadm doesn't run under root/sudo

Tags: linux, open-iscsi

When attempting to discover iscsi targets using the following command, I get (as expected not running with sudo) the following:

iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p 192.168.1.199

Result:

> iscsiadm: Could not open /var/lock/iscsi: Permission denied iscsiadm:
> Could not open /var/lock/iscsi: Permission denied

When attempting to run elevated:

sudo iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p 192.168.1.199

I get the folowing:

> sudo: iscsiadm: command not found

Is there something missing in the path statement, otherwise what am I missing?

Running on an asustor AS5304T NAS (I understand it to be running open-iscsi):

Linux mynas 5.13.x #1 SMP Fri Apr 14 00:13:58 CST 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I've not had this issue on any other device/distro before.

Comment: Add full path to `iscsiadm` command.